# Reason for finding low boron levels in clayey soil with high organic matter?

Tags: geochemistry, soil, soil-science, nutrient-cycles

I've read from various University Extension sites (e.g., [here](https://ag.umass.edu/vegetable/fact-sheets/boron-deficiency) and [here](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/why_does_boron_show_up_on_my_soil_test_report)) that **boron levels would be deficient in sandy soils with low organic matter**.

- This would suggest that boron levels would be *higher* in non-sandy soils with *high* organic matter (OM) levels.

However, in a series of upland forest patches in central NC with clayey (low sand) soils with substantial OM, **I've found the opposite to be true: Soil boron-levels in these low sand/high OM plots were regionally amongst the lowest levels measured** (<0.2 ppm; more than 4x lower than nearby sandy soils with low OM).

- This seems to contradict the above stated trend from extension websites.

Question: What would cause this trend? **What would cause boron levels to be so deficient in clayey (non sandy) high OM soil?**

*Other information about sites:* relatively dry, high topographic position and exposure, acidic (pH < 6) soil, high {K, Al, S} in soil. Vegetation = mid-to-late successional mixed hardwood/oak-hickory forests with relatively open understory due to deer overbrowse.

<sub>Note: soil methods: Mehlich III extraction for plant nutrients; loss-on-ignition method for OM.</sub>

Comment: What type of bedrock are your sites on? Is it the same for all sites?